# Spacing within equation

Tags: spacing, equations, amsmath

I've got the following equation:

```
\begin{align*}
y_{i} &= f(x_{i}) + \epsilon_{i} \nonumber \\
&\approx \underbrace{f(x_{0})}_\text{=$\beta_{0}$} + (x_{i}-x_{0})\underbrace{f^{'}(x_{0})}_\text{=$\beta_{1}$} + (x_{i}-x_{0})^{2}\underbrace{\frac{f^{''}(x_{0})}{2!}}_\text{=$\beta_{2}$} + \ldots + (x_{i}-x_{0})^{l}\underbrace{\frac{f^{(l)}(x_{0})}{l!}}_\text{=$\beta_{l}$}  +  \epsilon_{i}  \nonumber \\
&= \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}(x_{i}-x_{0}) + \beta_{2}(x_{i}-x_{0})^{2} + \ldots + \beta_{l}(x_{i}-x_{0})^{l}  +  \epsilon_{i} \ . 
\end{align*}
```

However, on the second line the `\epsilon_{i}`part doesn't have a space after the '+'. I'm not sure why that is. Is there way I can have a space after the '+', i.e. 'proper' spacing?

Thanks!

Comment: The (lack of) spacing issue occurs repeatedly, not just in the `+\epsilon` instance. You should encase the various `\text{...}` instructions in pairs of curly braces.

Comment: removed the `align` tag -- the same thing will happen within `\[ ... \]` or in any other display environment.

Comment: By the way, it's not the point of your question, but if you type `f^{'}` in math the prime symbol comes out too small and too high. You want to type `f'` or `f^{\prime}`. Typing `f^{'}` is like typing `f^{^{\prime}}`, in which the prime symbol is in scriptscriptstyle and raised twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Before

[image]

### After

[image]

You need `{}` before `+\epsilon{i}`. Or enclose each `\underbrace` with `{}` as follows.

```
{\underbrace{f(x_0)}_{=\beta_0}}
```

I also removed unnecessary `{}` in your original code to save more data storage and to make your code more readable and easier to maintain.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax
\begin{align*}
y_i
&= 
f(x_i) + \epsilon_i
\\%======================================================================
&\approx
    {\underbrace{f(x_0)}_{=\beta_0}}
+ (x_i-x_0){\underbrace{f'(x_0)}_{=\beta_1}}
+ (x_i-x_0)^2{\underbrace{\frac{f''(x_0)}{2!}}_{=\beta_2}}
+ \ldots 
+ (x_i-x_0)^l{\underbrace{\frac{f^{(l)}(x_0)}{l!}}_{=\beta_l}}
+ \epsilon_i
\\%======================================================================
&= 
    \beta_0
+ \beta_1(x_i-x_0) 
+ \beta_2(x_i-x_0)^2
+ \ldots 
+ \beta_l(x_i-x_0)^l 
+ \epsilon_i
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This problem occurs because something like `\underbrace{...}_{...}` is a large operator like `\sum` (*TeXBook* page 176), and when something like `+` that's normally a binary operator immediately follows a large operator, the binary operator gets turned into an ordinary symbol (*TeXBook* page 442, step 5). But anything enclosed in braces is treated as an ordinary symbol, so `{\underbrace{...}_{...}}` allows the `+` to remain a binary operator (i.e., to get the usual space around it). These extra braces also make there be no extra space to the left of any underbraced item but the first. Right?